# Name of Logarithmic Curve

Tags: logarithms

I was playing with the Desmos graphing calculator and "discovered" the following curve $(\ln x)^2 + (\ln y)^2 = 1$ (I originally found it in the parametric form $(e^{\cos t}, e^{\sin t})$). It would seem to be the equivalent of a circle on a log-log plot mapped back into a rectangular plot. Is it at all well-known, and does it have a name?

A graph of some similar (circle-ish) curves, suggested by commenters:

[image: Image of several similar curves from desmos]

Might any of those have names either?

Comment: Very intriguing. I wonder, what do the rational points on it look like?

Comment: $(\ln(x)\pm1)^2+(\ln(y))^2=1$ are interesting, too.

Comment: Not all curves have their own names.

Comment: It seems like it's trying to be a circle centered on $(1,1)$, but it's shying away from the axes. (Contrast that with $\dfrac1{x^2}+\dfrac1{y^2}=1$, which seems like it's trying to be a circle centered at $(0,0)$, but it's going _around_ the axes.)

Comment: $\arcsin^2(x)+\arcsin^2(y)=1$ is another nice graph.

Comment: I guess perhaps it is not well-studied enough (or just not useful enough) to have a name.